# SQL How to join rows as column headers in a Pivot?

Tags: sql-server, join, pivot-table

I have the following 2 tables:

TagNames:

| TagName | TagIndex |
| --- | --- |
| Name1 | 0 |
| Name2 | 1 |
| Name3 | 2 |

TagValues:

| DateAndTime | TagIndex | Val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-08 09:31:51.000 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-02-08 09:31:51.000 | 1 | 10 |
| 2023-02-08 09:31:51.000 | 2 | 20 |
| 2023-02-08 09:32:01.000 | 0 | 1 |
| 2023-02-08 09:32:01.000 | 1 | 11 |
| 2023-02-08 09:32:01.000 | 2 | 21 |

Using this query I managed to fetch the rows as cols

```
WITH Tags AS (
   SELECT
      T.[TagIndex],
      T.[DateAndTime],
      T.[Val]
   FROM
      [dbo].[TagValues] T
      INNER JOIN [dbo].[TagNames] N
         ON T.TagIndex = N.TagIndex
)
SELECT *
FROM
   Tags
   PIVOT (MAX([Val]) FOR [TagIndex] IN ([0], [1], [2])) P
   ORDER BY DateAndTime
;
```

Obtaining as result something like this:

| DateAndTime | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-08 09:31:51.000 | 0 | 10 | 20 |
| 2023-02-08 09:32:01.000 | 1 | 11 | 21 |

What I want to do is substitute the column headers with TagName in the first table

Comment: Personally, I often feel that such requirements are something for your presentation layer, not the SQL Layer. You *must* explicitly define your column (aliases) in SQL, so you have to use dynamic SQL to give them *dynamic* names. A presentation layer, however, often doesn't have that restriction when it is *presenting* the data; you can define the names of the columns displayed programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with dynamic SQL, as I describe in [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand):

```
DECLARE @TagNameCols nvarchar(max), @sql nvarchar(max);
SELECT @TagNameCols = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(tn.TagName),',')
  FROM dbo.TagNames AS tn
  WHERE TagIndex IN (SELECT TagIndex FROM dbo.TagValues);

SELECT @sql = N'WITH Tags AS (
   SELECT
      N.[TagName],
      T.[DateAndTime],
      T.[Val]
   FROM
      [dbo].[TagValues] T
      INNER JOIN [dbo].[TagNames] N
         ON T.TagIndex = N.TagIndex
)
SELECT *
FROM
   Tags
   PIVOT (MAX([Val]) FOR [TagName] IN (' + @TagNameCols + N')) P
   ORDER BY DateAndTime
;';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

- Working [db<>fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/iaGQs603)